# Crystal Report not showing data even though dataset contains data from MSAccess - what am I missing?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset, report

```
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ssql As String

    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= 'C:\Users\xxxx\xxxxx\xxxxxxxxe/xxxxxx.accdb'"
    con.Open()
    ssql = "SELECT * FROM tblTempProformaInvoice"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(ssql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "GetProformaInvoice")
    con.Close()
    MsgBox(ds.Tables("GetProformaInvoice").Rows(0).Item("spinvnr").ToString)
    Dim rpt As New PFI
    rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
    CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
rpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
```